# PANIC: System call looped around EINTR 100 times

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When running the android emulator, I always get the following error message before the emulator process is killed.

```
PANIC: .//android/sockets.c:1002:int socket_recvfrom(int, void *, int, SockAddress *): 
System call looped around EINTR 100 times: recvfrom(fd,buf,len,0,sa.sa,&salen)
```

I am using Android SDK / AVD Manager on Mac OSX10.10 (64 bit) and Java version 1.7.0_65.

Does anyone know what this means, why this happens, and how it can be alleviated?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, there's a regression on the OSX version of the Android emulator that causes this:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70592